# Безопасность от XSS атак и SQL в Smarty

Tags: sql, безопасность, smarty, xss

Сайт построен на фреймворке *Flightphp*, шаблонизаторе *Smarty*. Единственный инпут от пользователя (форма комментариев), очищается от тегов перед вставкой в бд. Работа с бд с помощью PDO.

**Необходимо ли любой вывод оборачивать в [escape](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape)?**

В целях безопасности от XSS-атак и SQL-инъекций что еще следует применить на сайте?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно данные поступающие от пользователя в базу данных не изменяются, а хранятся как есть. Большинство предпочитает экранировать вывод на страницу, например, при помощи htmlspecialchars(). В противном случае у вас могут быть сложности, если потом потребуется редактирование данных - каждый раз будут добавляться все новые и новые символы экранирования.

Comment: Так в Smarty `escape` это и есть `htmlspecialchars`? Надо прописать его ко всем выводам переменных? Есть способ установить это по дефолту?